# Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

> I am trying to write jest test case for submit function which has
>   JSON.parse involed in it. Below is the code and test case for it.

```
handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let requestData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.tempAddRequest));
            if (e.target[1].value.length === 0) {
                this.setState({ rrNumberFeedback: true, rrNumberErr: FIELD_ERROR });
            }
}

 it("should check if rr is null on clicking submit button in modal", () => {
        const instance = wrapper.instance();
        const e = {
            target: [{ name: "branchNumber", value: "" }, { name: "rrNumber", value: "" }, { name: "crdNumber", value: "1234" }],
            preventDefault: () => { }
        }
        instance.handleFormSubmit(e);
        expect(wrapper.state('rrNumberErr')).toEqual("E");
        expect(wrapper.state('rrNumberFeedback')).toEqual(true);
    });
```

Comment: You need to first check whether the JSON you are trying to parse is a valid JSON, try this to validate the same https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: if you are using `JSON.parse()` make sure you are sending stringified JSON, to it

Comment: JSON.parse<>JSON.stringify,two are vice-versa - you must use one at time,not both.

Comment: @sumanthmadishetty saying `stringified  JSON` is redundant (or would imply that you stringify the JSON again, which would have a completely different effect), you can say something like, an object that was stringified to JSON.

Comment: The unexpected token **u** and in combination with position **0**, indicated that you a variable that holds `undefined` into `JSON.parse`.  The only `JSON.parse` in the shown code would not result in that error, so the problem has to be somewhere else. A full copy and paste of the error message including the complete stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: are you sure to send value in `e.target` rather than `e.target.value`

Answer (score 0):

[image: refer to this image]If the `handleFormSubmit` involves `JSON.parse()` you need to send the stringified JSON in the value of event

try changing `event` as

```
const e = {
        target: JSON.stringify([{ name: "branchNumber", value: "" }, { name: "rrNumber", value: "" }, { name: "crdNumber", value: "1234" }]),
        preventDefault: () => { }
    }
```

Comment: The unexpected token in the question is `u` and not `o`. And that e.g. happens if `undefined` is passed to `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @t.niese My bad for not going through the question properly